# How can I duplicate parented objects properly?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

So I am working on a sculpt with seperate eyes. I parented this pupil to the eyeball, but when i try to duplicate it just the eyeball gets duplicated. How can I do this properly without joining the pupil to the eye mesh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple anser is: select both of them. It's easier to see in wireframe mode. When you duplicate several objects together, their relationships get copied, too.

If you have selected both of them and the pupil doesn't move, it may be the pupil's location is locked. It will be duplicated but it won't move, so you have two pupils at the old position.

Comment: in this case it is the best way. But I wonder what to do if there were much more objects as in this case.